# Unable to search username based on filter in WSO2 SCIM REST api

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am new to WSO2 Identity Server-5.11.0 , I want to search user based on username using scim api however nothing works for me

```
https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users?userNameEqadmin@wso2.com
https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users?filter=userNameEqadmin@wso2.com
https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users?filter=userName=admin@wso2.com
https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users?filter=userName Eq admin@wso2.com
https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users?filter=username=admin@wso2.com
https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users?filter=usernameEqadmin@wso2.com
```

Can anyone suggest proper search criteria to use ?

Comment: Below is the search criteria , [user_store]
user_name_attribute = "mail"
user_name_search_filter = "(&amp;(objectClass=person)(mail=?))"
user_name_list_filter = "(&amp;(objectClass=person)(!(sn=Service)))"
username_java_script_regex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'
username_java_regex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}'

Comment: Some improvement : I am able to get using https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users?filter=userName Eq admin whoever it doesnot work with email, on response I am getting {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "schemas": [
        "urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"
    ],
    "Resources": [
        {
            "meta": {
                "location": "https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users/admin@wso2.com"
            },
            "id": "fed8c7c9-9505-4494-a170-628a5660d492",
            "userName": "admin@wso2.com"
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with `POSTMAN` and I'm getting data

`URL`
`https://{your host here}/t/{tenant domain}/scim2/Users/.search`

`Authorization`
You can give `basic Auth` for now

`body`
You can give search variable like this

```
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:SearchRequest"
    ],
    "attributes": [
        "userName"
    ],
    "filter": "userName Eq SigningOfficer",
    "domain": "PRIMARY",
    "startIndex": 1,
    "count": 10
}
```

It is a `POST` method.

For more reference you can try this link

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/scim2-rest-apis/#/Groups%20Endpoint/getGroupsByPost

Comment: thanks issue can be closed

Comment: @manojx hope your issue is fixed. If you find answer you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have used SCIM 1.0 protocol.
It's better to use SCIM 2.0 because latest versions of IS supports SCIM 2.0
Refer: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/scim2-rest-apis/

So the correct SCIM request for user filtering based on exact username match is:

`https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users?filter=userName eq admin@wso2.com`

Even if the above request doesn't satisfy your query,

Please verify whether you have followed all the steps in https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/using-email-address-as-the-username/#using-email-address-as-the-username in the same order.

Especially, if you have missed this step you won't be able to filter from username by giving the email.

```
Login to the management console and configure the Mapped Attribute property of the http://wso2.org/claims/username claim ID that is under Dialect dialectURI http://wso2.org/claims to mail.
```

Comment: Thanks the solution works, out of curiosity is this change only via going into UI or is there any file ( json ) where this can be incorporated.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question

Comment: The step "Login to the management console and configure the Mapped Attribute property of the http://wso2.org/claims/username claim ID that is under Dialect dialectURI http://wso2.org/claims to mail.
Share" as you mentioned is it possible to automate it via updating any json file rather manually going through UI.